# Increasing 5MB Storage Limit in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, local-storage

We have a POS app written in html5 and we are using the localStorage to store orders and other info.

I am experiencing the limits of the 5MB that chrome offers and it is causing the app to crash.

Is there an easy way to increase this limitation?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-html5/browse_thread/thread/e911f18b905d28ee?pli=1), it discusses your problem and it might help you

> The db file path for chromium and chrome on windows vista look like...
>
> ```
> C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default\Application Cache\Index 
> C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Application Cache
> ```
>
> Here's the sql statement to run...
>
> ```
> insert into Quota values("http://127.0.0.1:8008/", 100000000);
> ```
>
> You can run that command using the sqlite3 command line tool available
> here, http://www.sqlite.org/download.html. Put whatever origin url you'd to
> give more storage to in there.

Comment: There is no such table "Quota" in this database... :-(

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to increase 5MB localStorage per-domain limit. You can use **IndexedDB** instead for storing your data, though. Read more: [IndexedDB and Limits](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/17/indexeddb-and-limits)